# Not getting integer value from properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I want to read the integer value from the key which I defined in application.properties file. Here is my properties file.

> spring.rabbitmq.port=31111

And here is the code:

```
public Object getPortProperty() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:application.properties");
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        properties.load(in);
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    return (Integer) properties.get("spring.rabbitmq.port");

}

@Autowired
public UnitAmqpRestController(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) throws IOException, TimeoutException {
    this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
    rabbitTemplate.setReplyTimeout(15_000L);
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost(getHostProperty());
    factory.setPort((Integer) getPortProperty());
    connection = factory.newConnection();
    channel = connection.createChannel();
}
```

Getting the following error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'unitAmqpRestController' defined in URL
>   [jar:file:/tmp/unitamqpservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/abc/ci/unitamqpservice/UnitAmqpRestController.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [com.abc.ci.unitamqpservice.UnitAmqpRestController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e7ff3f42]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:279)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
>   ~[spring-context-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
>   [spring-boot-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.10.RELEASE]
>           at com.abc.ci.unitamqpservice.UnitamqpserviceApplication.main(UnitamqpserviceApplication.java:10)
>   [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
>   [unitamqpservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>   [unitamqpservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
>   [unitamqpservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
>   [unitamqpservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [com..ci.unitamqpservice.UnitAmqpRestController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e7ff3f42]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:271)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           ... 26 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>           at com.abc.ci.unitamqpservice.UnitAmqpRestController.(UnitAmqpRestController.java:75)
>   ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>           at com.abc.ci.unitamqpservice.UnitAmqpRestController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e7ff3f42.()
>   ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_212]
>           at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.14.RELEASE]
>           ... 28 common frames omitted

I am not able to understand why it is not working with the integer. if I have a string value, it works perfectly. 
please suggest what is wrong in the code

The problematic line of the code is:

```
factory.setPort((Integer) getPortProperty());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is throwing a `NullPointerException` and you have an empty `catch` block. At the bare minimum you should add some logging in there to see what's happening.

Also, you're using Spring and should rarely need to parse `application.properties` manually; it automatically gets loaded into the application environment.

So you can use `@Value` to bind it to a local variable instead (same for host property):

```
@Value("${spring.rabbitmq.port}")
private int mqPort;

@Value("${spring.rabbitmq.host}")
private String mqHost;

@Autowired
public UnitAmqpRestController(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) throws IOException, TimeoutException {
    this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
    rabbitTemplate.setReplyTimeout(15_000L);
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost(mqHost);
    factory.setPort(mqPort);
    connection = factory.newConnection();
    channel = connection.createChannel();
}
```

Additionally, you should consider using the [Spring Boot Rabbit MQ starter](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-rabbitmq/) module to manage your Rabbit MQ connections and properties instead of managing it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Having `spring.rabbitmq.port=31111` in `application.properties` or `yml`, read it using the [`@Value`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) annotation which reads the property and parses to a correct type:

```
@Value("${spring.rabbitmq.port=31111}")
private int port;
```

The class itself should be recognizable as a bean using either `@Configuration` or any variation of `@Component` such as `@Service`.

If you want to load a property using a method as you do, consider using a special method for the integers:

```
private int getIntegerProperty(final String key, final int defaultValue) {
    final Object object = properties.get("spring.rabbitmq.port")
    if (object == null || "".equals(object.toString())) {
        return defaultValue;
    } else {
        return Integer.parseInt(object );
    }
}
```